# Deploy Azure SQL Database Objects

Tags: sql, database, azure, deployment

Is there a preferred way to deploying database objects (tables, views) for an azure sql database?  Should they be deployed with a bacpac?  or Use Jenkins pipeline to deploy db objects?

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If your database is on premise SQL Server database, you can deploy the data to Azure directly with SSMS `Deploy Database to SQL Azure...`:

[image]

I think this is the simplest way. You also can use [Data Migration Assistant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/dma/dma-overview?view=sql-server-ver15) or create the bacpac file and then deploy it to Azure SQL.

If your database is Azure SQL database, the best way for you is create a bacpac file and then import it to Azure SQL server.

Reference: [Quickstart: Import a BACPAC file to a database in Azure SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-import).

Hope this helps.